# Blazor IL trimming with (almost) no results

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Am I missing something about the procedures and effects of IL trimming in Blazor WebAssembly apps? I've made a test with Visual Studio (16.8.4) template generated WebAssembly Blazor app. In debug mode Chrome dev tools tells me that, for the home page, **203 requests were made, 9.4Mb transferred and 23.4 Mb resources**.

I've published this app to a site and there the numbers are:  **194 requests, 12.8Mb transferred, 24.8 Mb resources**. I've tried to add: `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>` to my `csproj` file, supposely the default, and in fact there were no changes. If on the contrary I use: `<PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>` the numbers are slightly worse: 202 requests | 13.2Mb transferred | 23.4 Mb resources. The tag `<TrimMode>link</TrimMode>` also does not effect on the results.

Is this what I should expect as the "significantly smaller" published application or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. App size is over 20MB!